# When should I use classes and self method in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I've been trying to write a Python program to calculate a point location, based on distance from 4 anchors. I decided to calculate it as intersection points of 4 circles.

I have a question regarding not the algorithm but rather the use of classes in such program. I don't really have much experience with OOP. Is it really necessary to use classes here or does it at least improve a program in any way?

Here's my code:

```
import math

class Program():
    def __init__(self, anchor_1, anchor_2, anchor_3, anchor_4, data):
        self.anchor_1 = anchor_1
        self.anchor_2 = anchor_2
        self.anchor_3 = anchor_3
        self.anchor_4 = anchor_4



    def intersection(self, P1, P2, dist1, dist2): 
        PX = abs(P1[0]-P2[0])               
        PY = abs(P1[1]-P2[1])
        d = math.sqrt(PX*PX+PY*PY)   

        if d < dist1+ dist2 and d > (abs(dist1-dist2)):

            ex = (P2[0]-P1[0])/d
            ey = (P2[1]-P1[1])/d

            x = (dist1*dist1 - dist2*dist2 + d*d) / (2*d)
            y = math.sqrt(dist1*dist1 - x*x)

            P3 = ((P1[0] + x * ex - y * ey),(P1[1] + x*ey + y*ex))
            P4 = ((P1[0] + x * ex + y * ey),(P1[1] + x*ey - y*ex))  

            return (P3,P4)
        elif d == dist1 + dist2:
            ex = (P2[0]-P1[0])/d
            ey = (P2[1]-P1[1])/d

            x = (dist1*dist1 - dist2*dist2 + d*d) / (2*d)
            y = math.sqrt(dist1*dist1 - x*x)

            P3 = ((P1[0] + x * ex + y * ey),(P1[1] + x*ey + y*ex))

            return(P3, None)
        else:
            return (None, None)





    def calc_point(self, my_list):
        if len(my_list) != 5:
            print("Wrong data")
        else:
            tag_id = my_list[0];
            self.dist_1 = my_list[1];
            self.dist_2 = my_list[2];
            self.dist_3 = my_list[3];
            self.dist_4 = my_list[4];

        (self.X1, self.X2) = self.intersection(self.anchor_1, self.anchor_2, self.dist_1, self.dist_2)
        (self.X3, self.X4) = self.intersection(self.anchor_1, self.anchor_3, self.dist_1, self.dist_3)
        (self.X5, self.X6) = self.intersection(self.anchor_1, self.anchor_4, self.dist_1, self.dist_4)





with open('distances.txt') as f:
    dist_to_anchor = f.readlines()

dist_to_anchor = [x.strip() for x in dist_to_anchor]
dist_to_anchor = [x.split() for x in dist_to_anchor]
for row in dist_to_anchor:
    for k in range(0,5):
        row[k] = float(row[k])
anchor_1= (1,1)
anchor_2 = (-1,1)
anchor_3 = (-1, -1)
anchor_4 = (1, -1)

My_program = Program (anchor_1, anchor_2, anchor_3, anchor_4, dist_to_anchor)
My_program.calc_point(dist_to_anchor[0])

print(My_program.X1)
print(My_program.X2)
print(My_program.X3)
print(My_program.X4)
print(My_program.X5)
print(My_program.X6)
```

Also, I don't quite understand where should I use self keyword and where it is needless.

Comment: `self` is not a keyword. It's an identifier, just like `my_list` or `f` or `anchor_1`.

Comment: Take the lesson: [Python - Object Oriented](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)

Comment: Wrapping a program inside a class is not an adequate approach to OOP style. But the answers here give you several ideas to different approaches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classes and OOP are IMHO always a good choice, by using them, you will be able to better organize and reuse your code, you can create new classes that derive from an existing class to extend its functionality (inheritance) or to change its behavior if you need it to (polymorphism) as well as to encapsulate the internals of your code so it becomes safer (no real encapsulation in Python, though).

In your specific case, for example, you are building a calculator, that uses a technique to calculate an intersection, if somebody else using your class wants to modify that behavior they could override the function (this is Polymorphism in action):

```
class PointCalculator:
    def intersection(self, P1, P2, dist1, dist2): 
        # Your initial implementation

class FasterPointCalculator(PointCalculator):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def intersection(self, P1, P2, dist1, dist2):
        # New implementation
```

Or, you might extend the class in the future:

```
class BetterPointCalculator(PointCalculator):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

        def distance(self, P1, P2):
            # New function
```

You may need to initialize your class with some required data and you may not want users to be able to modify it, you could indicate encapsulation by naming your variables with an underscore:

```
class PointCalculator:
    def __init__(self, p1, p2):
        self._p1 = p1
        self._p2 = p2

    def do_something(self): 
        # Do something with your data
        self._p1 + self._p2
```

As you have probably noticed, self is passed automatically when calling a function, it contains a reference to the current object (the instance of the class) so you can access anything declared in it like the variables _p1 and _p2 in the example above.

You can also create class methods (static methods) and then you don't have access to self, you should do this for methods that perform general calculations or any operation that doesn't need a specific instance, your intersection method could be a good candidate e.g.

```
class PointCalculator:

    @staticmethod
    def intersection(P1, P2, dist1, dist2): 
        # Return the result
```

Now you don't need an instance of PointCalculator, you can simply call `PointCalculator.intersection(1, 2, 3, 4)`

Another advantage of using classes could be memory optimization, Python will delete objects from memory when they go out of scope, so if you have a long script with a lot of data, they will not be released from memory until the script terminates.

Having said that, for small utility scripts that perform very specific tasks, for example, install an application, configure some service, run some OS administration task, etc... a simple script is totally fine and it is one of the reasons Python is so popular.

Answer (score 10):

> Is it really necessary to use classes here or does it at least improve a program in any way?

Classes are never necessary, but they are often very useful for organizing code.

In your case, you've taken procedural code and just wrapped it in a class. It's still basically a bunch of function calls. You'd be better off *either* writing it as procedures *or* writing proper classes.

---

Let's look at how you'd do some geometry in a [*procedural* style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) vs an [object oriented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) style.

Procedural programming is all about writing functions (procedures) which take some data, process it, and return some data.

```
def area_circle(radius):
    return math.pi * radius * radius

print(area_circle(5))
```

You have the radius of a circle and you get the area.

Object oriented programming is about asking data to do things.

```
class Circle():
    def __init__(self, radius=0):
        self.radius = radius

    def area(self):
        return math.pi * self.radius * self.radius

circle = Circle(radius=5)
print(circle.area())
```

You have a circle and you ask it for its area.

That seems a lot of extra code for a very subtle distinction. Why bother?

What happens if you need to calculate other shapes? Here's a Square in OO.

```
class Square():
    def __init__(self, side=0):
        self.side = side
    
    def area(self):
        return self.side * self.side

square = Square(side=5)
print(square.area())
```

And now procedural.

```
def area_square(side):
    return side * side
print(area_square(5));
```

So what? What happens when you want to calculate the area of a *shape*? Procedurally, everywhere that wants to deal with shapes has to know what sort of shape it's dealing with and what procedure to call on it and where to get that procedure from. This logic might be scattered all over the code. To avoid this you could write a wrapper function and make sure its imported as needed.

```
from circle import 'area_circle'
from square import 'area_square'

def area(type, shape_data):
    if type == 'circle':
        return area_circle(shape_data)
    elif type == 'square':
        return area_square(shape_data)
    else:
        raise Exception("Unrecognized type")

print(area('circle', 5))
print(area('square', 5))
```

In OO you get that for free.

```
print(shape.area())
```

Whether `shape` is a `Circle` or a `Square`, `shape.area()` will work.  You, the person using the shape, don't need to know anything about how it works. If you want to do more with your shapes, perhaps calculate the perimeter, add a `perimeter` method to your shape classes and now it's available wherever you have a shape.

As more shapes get added the procedural code gets more and more complex everywhere it needs to use shapes. The OO code remains exactly the same, instead you write more classes.

And that's the point of OO: hiding the details of how the work is done behind an interface. It doesn't matter to your code how it works so long as the result is the same.